# Kubernetes multi region deployment

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

We have an application which is deployed on gcloud using Kubernetes. The application can be deployed from the master branch of git as well as any git branches we create. We are now moving to a multi-regional deployment of our application.

The question is will branch deployment be supported in multi-regional deployments? For a multi-regional deployment, I am using the kubemci tool.

Has anyone used this tool and done something similar? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you manage your git branches is not directly related to managing a multi-cluster ingress with `kubemci`.

To manage your branches and deployments (even multi-region) I suggest you look at [GitOps](https://www.weave.works/technologies/gitops/) tools in Kubernetes. Some of them:

- [Flux](https://github.com/weaveworks/flux)
- [Skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold)
- [GitKube](https://github.com/hasura/gitkube)
- [Draft](https://github.com/Azure/draft)
- [Ksonnet](https://ksonnet.io/)
- [Argo](https://github.com/argoproj/argo)

You can still use `kubemci` to manage your ingresses in your clusters across multi-regions.